# Joomla AdsManager filter list on field based

Tags: php, joomla, components

I am working for a website based sj live template adsmanger component. I need to add a filter in list view for filtering of a field ad_location. i have write code to create a dropdown for all locations and each option value is like below

```
<?php echo TRoute::_("index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=list&catid=".$this->catid."&ad_location=".$fields->fieldvalueid); ?>
```

but when i select an option the url becomes like this

```
index.php/ads-manager/6-verktyg-foer-fordon?ad_location=58
```

or

```
index.php/ads-manager/6-verktyg-foer-fordon?ad_location=paris
```

but page reload with the same result as it was before.
I have select "Ads can be sorted by this field?" for location field yes.

please instruct me how do i acheive this so that a specific categorie can be filtered on the bases of location.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This happens as your sef url is enabled. Check by disabling the sef option. If that works then you may have to modify the router.php fily of adsmanager component.

Comment: issue is not SEF url. i m wanted location drop down on the list view should works like order filter works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adsmanager list view have no ordering for filters other then date. therefore there is need to use result view and therefore the option value should be like this

```
`<?php echo TRoute::_("index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=result&new_search=1&catid=".$this->catid."&ad_location=".$fields->fieldvalueid); ?>`
```

and also one i have missed to use correct value of field id that should be `fieldvalue` instead of `fieldvalueid` so the option values should be looks like this

```
<?php echo TRoute::_("index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=result&new_search=1&catid=".$this->catid."&ad_location=".$fields->fieldvalueid); ?>
```

and full code for location field will be like this

```
<select onchange="jumpmenu('parent',this)">         
        <option value="<?php echo TRoute::_("index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=result&new_search=1&catid=".$this->catid); ?>">Please Select a Location</option>
        <?php 
        $ad_location = JRequest::getVar('ad_location');
        $fieldmodel     = $this->getModel("field");
        $field_values = $fieldmodel->getFieldValues();
        foreach($field_values[17] as $fields){ //print_r($fields); ?>
        <option value="<?php echo TRoute::_("index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=result&new_search=1&catid=".$this->catid."&ad_location=".$fields->fieldvalue); ?>" <?php if ($fields->fieldvalue == $ad_location) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> ><?php echo $fields->fieldtitle; ?></option>
        <?php }?>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below the solution is not exactly match but you can try to use the logic.
You can create custom function, form submit every option selected value to get value of name ,the results in sql**

```
  Class AdsLocation {

        public static function ListLocations($selected = -1) {
            $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', '-1', JText::_('Filter Locations') );
            $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', 'USA', JText::_('USA') );
            .
            .
            .
            $uri = JFactory::getURI();
            $uri->delVar('limitstart');
            $uri->delVar('start'); 

            $attr  = 'onchange="this.form.action=\''.$uri.'\';';
            $attr .= ' this.form.submit();"';
            $attr .= " class='select'";
            return JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options, 'filter_location', $attr, 'value', 'text', $selected);  
    }
}
```

You can use the class name of function name selected id,name

ex:  **Load page: echo AdsLocation::ListLocations('USA');**

**Get the value JRequest::getVar('filter_location');**

Comment: thanks for your good effort. where should i use both
ex: Load page: echo AdsLocation::ListLocations('USA');

Get the value JRequest::getVar('filter_location');
it will be great help.

Comment: which views (list/grid) use this code , echo AdsLocation::ListLocations('USA');  model GetItems sql query -- JRequest::getVar('filter_location'); if(JRequest::getVar('filter_location') > -1) { }

Comment: it will only in drop down location field which i have already added. i need to change list controller so that it will accept location filter to change result of list view.

Comment: yes .that's correct ..you filter by location in controller file.